# Aurelia compose element: childContainer is not defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I want to leverage the `<compose>` custom element in my application using the `view` property exclusively. Here is my markup/code:

### app.html

```
<template>
    <main>
        <compose view="views/start.html"></compose>
    </main>
</template>
```

### app.js

```
import { Metadata } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class App {
    static metadata() { return Metadata.singleton(); }
    constructor() { }
}
```

### /views/start.html

```
<template>
    <section>
        <button>New game</button>
    </section>
</template>
```

However, I get the following error:

> Potentially unhandled rejection [1] ReferenceError: childContainer is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that has been resolved. See here:

https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/6